Which biblatex bibliography style is closest to utphys?
I have been using the utphys BibTeX bibliography style for a long time.  Recently some younger collaborators have decided to use BibLaTeX instead and I'm wondering whether there is a bibliography style which is close to utphys in its functionality.

There's a good listing over at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles

Very broadly speaking and overgeneralising a lot: If you write English papers in a STEM field, cite mainly English papers/books and have a well curated .bib file, you probably will not benefit a lot from choosing biblatex over classical BibTeX. This is especially true if you already have a bibliography and citation setup that you like.
biblatex offers a lot of awesome features and is a great help when it comes to implement complex styles that are used in the local traditions of some humanities. It supports output in a variety of languages and can be configured for as-of-yet unsupported languages as well. It can deal natively with Unicode and is therefore the only good way to deal with sources that feature lot of of non-ASCII chars. Its sourcemapping feature allows you to modify the .bib data on the fly and can help clean up some dodgy .bib data (though it is of course much better to have a solid .bib file in the first place). And just to emphasise it again: biblatex makes it so much easier than BibTeX to write your own bibliography/citation style and to modify and existing one.
Switching your current setup to biblatex will come at a cost. The immediate changes required in the document code or your coding habits are fairly small (What to do to switch to biblatex?) as are the changes required in your workflow (run Biber instead of BibTeX). But you will probably only be able to use biblatex to its full potential if you adapt your .bib file to its more extensive format. You will still get solid results if you just take your .bib file that you used with BibTeX, but some of the nice features require .bib data that is more finely tuned to biblatex's data model, which can be subtly different from what your BibTeX styles used to support. Finally, you should know that biblatex is still not very much liked by publishers. Many publishers have BibTeX styles they want you to use and even if they don't have a specific BibTeX style, they implicitly assume you use BibTeX (or write thebibliography by hand). Internally biblatex works very different from classical BibTeX/thebibliography and this may not be acceptable for some publisher workflows. Even the arXiv has some trouble with biblatex (Biblatex and arxiv, error).
If the benefits you expect from using biblatex don't outweigh those costs, switching to biblatex may not be your best choice. I always and wholeheartedly recommend biblatex to those who want to write their own citation and bibliography style because they have fixed requirements that are not met by any existing BibTeX or biblatex style (unless they submit to a journal that cannot accept biblatex submissions - which should definitely be checked beforehand), I also recommend its use when people cite a lot of non-English work with non-ASCII chars or if they need output in a language other than English. But if that is not you, you may not need biblatex.

That all said, I don't think there is a style that looks exactly like utphys. Depending on your closeness metric you might be content with just style=numeric, and be done with it.
If you want to be closer to utphys the following modification of numeric (via biblatex-ext's ext-numeric) might be a start. If you need more, just ask a new question focussing on one specific aspect of utphys you want to reproduce.
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-numeric,
  sorting=none,
  maxbibnames=999,
  giveninits=true,
  articlein=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\addspace}
    {\addcomma\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


